# Why does Mingw change my identifier name at compile time?

Tags: c++, mingw

I have a small C++ library, compiles fine on Linux (which is my main dev platform). Now I'm trying to build it on a windows machine (XP3) with Mingw, and compiling fails, due to an unexplainable error.
For example, say I have the following method in class AAA, in namespace aaa, declared in file aaa.h:

```
void AAA::DrawText( foo z );
```

When compiling file aaa.cpp (that holds of course the methods implementation), I get the following error:

```
D:\dev\[...]\aaa.cpp:644: error: no 'void aaa::AAA::DrawTextA( foo z )' member function declared in class 'aaa::AAA'
```

Yep, you got it, **no typo there**... the compiler **misread** somehow the functions name, and added a letter to the function identifier !!!

This is absolutely beneath my comprehension. Never had such an issue on Linux. How can mingw / Gcc *change* an identifier ?

Name mangling ? No, this happens after compiling.

I checked of course the exact command line (I use an IDE): nothing wrong:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -W  -O3 -Wall    -I..\include -I"C:\program files\OpenCV2.1\include\opencv"  -c D:\dev\...\aaa.cpp -o ..\obj\Release\src\aaa.o
```

**BUT**: if I rename the function to, say,  DrawTxt(), then everything goes fine (but I can't do that). This means to me that the identifier is **already defined** somewhere. Opencv lib ? Grepped the tree, found nothing... And yes, I searched also the current include folder, nothing close.

The other solution that I see is that there is somewhere (?) a macro like:

```
#define DrawText DrawTextA
```

that gets activated in some situation.

So my questions are:

- Are there other possibilities for this curious name replacement in my code ? To me, the macro is the only way, if the identifier was already declared elsewhere, it would just throw an error, a compiler **can not** (well...) abruply change/replace/edit an identifier.
- How can I trackdown the problem ?

Comment: You could try an `#undef DrawText` at the top of your file. If it works after that, it would confirm you're getting clobbered by a macro.

Comment: Clue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263688/using-detours-for-hooking-writing-text-in-notepad/3276164#3276164

Comment: A little attitude tip: Whenever you're tempted to ask, "why does my compiler ...", consider the alternative format "Where do I fail to understand why ...". While not impossible, it is generally very unlikely that your compiler is the root source of any given problem, and an open attitude and honest assessment of yourself will usually result in a more rewarding learning process.

Comment: And also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080635/others-library-define-naming-conflict ... and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779185/conflict-with-drawtext-function

Comment: Ok, thanks to all of you@kerrekSK, you're right, I was so astonished with this behaviour I didn't even hit 'DrawText' into SO search...

Comment: Sorry, its for @kerrek-sb (what"s this 5mn time limit for editing comment ??? ). Of course, I wasn't suggesting the compiler failed, just that I couldn't find the problem, as such a header failure is just supposed **not** to happen. I guess Windows will allways surprise me. The lesson is that even namespaces can't protect your code against (evil) macros.

Comment: @kebs: No worries. I think we're all a little helpless in the face of `windows.h` :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I'm almost certain it's because somewhere this happens:

```
#define DrawText DrawTextA
```

Why? Because the suffix `A` often means "ascii" opposed to the suffix `W` which means "wide" (often for unicode). This is a common practice in Windows code to unify ascii and unicode builds with a simple define switch.

Also, it seems that the functions exists in the Windows library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms901121.aspx. Is `windows.h` is included in your project?

Comment: That line is in <winuser.h>. I bet somebody is #include'ing <windows.h> in your project.

Answer (score 4):

You included windows.h and the DrawText macro replaced DrawText with DrawTextA.

There's not a whole lot you can do about that other than avoid using names that Windows also uses. Not very appealing.

Comment: How about #defining `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`? Maybe that reduces the noise a bit.

Comment: @kerrek may help but DrawText will still be there. It's a pretty terrible state of affairs.